# Shuffling of an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, collections, shuffle

I have written a method to shuffle a String array So the task is to implement WhiteElephant concept(*All of the participants' names are placed into a container (hat, box, bag, etc) and mixed up. Each person then chooses one name from the container, but doesn't tell anyone which name was picked. He/she is now responsible for buying a gift for the person selected.*)
 for a given string array of list of names.Should generate assignments to match the original elements. I have written method to pick a random number and used a map to store the values so that each array value will have a different index. But this prints out only 5 values. and i am confused now.
** A person must be assigned to another person; no person must be assigned to himself/herself.

```
public static String[] generateAssignments(final String[] participants) {

   Random r = new Random();
   int size = participants.length;
   HashMap val = new HashMap();
   int change = 0;
   String[] assignments = new String[6];
   System.out.println("Using arrays");


   for(int i=0; i<size;i++) {
       for(int j =0; j<size; j++) {
           change = r.nextInt(size);
           if(val.containsValue(change) || change==i) {
               continue;
           }
           else val.put(i, change);
           assignments[i] = participants[change];
           System.out.println(assignments[i]);
           break;
       }   

   }

   return assignments;
}
```

I appreciate your inputs. Thanks, Lucky

Comment: Your print line is not executed on all loops. What does `continue;` do?

Comment: This question looks like homework to me. While asking homework questions is perfectly fine, there are some good guidelines for asking homework questions here: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/238586). Summarized, they are: make an attempt to solve the problem yourself first; ask about _specific_ problems with your _existing_ code; let us know that the question is homework; make sure your class allows using Q&A for help; don't copy and paste an answer's code without first understanding what it does and how it works.

Comment: I feel like your problem is with the `continue`. If the `change` value already exists or if the `change` value equals `i`, then it doesn't try to find a replacement--it just skips it.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat : thanks for lecturing me on that :). It is a task which i gotta do and i am not asking for copy paste code. Just looking for some pointers on what to do . Clearly from the code you could see i am not that good at java. if someone can jus give me a direction that will be great.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat homework questions aren't supposed to be treated differently from other questions

Comment: @JackRadcliffe: Well the continue will go back to the inner for loop which will run the line.  change = r.nextInt(size); to pick another random number. Also the inner loop shouldnt be limited 6 but like I said I am confused.

Comment: @SamIam Homework or not, this question doesn't meet my standards for work having been attempted. I'm not sure we're treating this any differently.

Comment: @user2988851 Yes, but it will still increment `j`. It doesn't guarantee that each one will be paired.

Answer (score 0):

If the point is to just have a mapping of people can't you just create an array that is of the appropriate length and store an int in each one?

ie

```
int len = participants.length;
int[] map = new int[len];
Random r = new Random();
String list = "";
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
   int n = r.nextInt(0, len);
   while((n == i) || (list.contains(n.toString()))){
      n = r.nextInt(0, len);
   }
   list = list + n.toString();
   map[i] = n;
}
```

That way you've filled an array with ints corresponding to people who are also assigned ints.

Comment: Please review int r = new Random ();

Comment: Still, new Random() is an object and therefore not assignable to int. Further the array isn't initialized, which results in an exception. No offense.

Comment: @ThatDaveGuy : Thanks for the reply. At this line : int temp = new Random();    What if the temp == i again ?

Comment: @Pr0gr4mm3r: none taken. My Java is rusty TBH. I see now what should happen I think and will be editing in just a moment to declare r outside the for loop and use the nextInt

Comment: @user2988851 if temp == i then r == i so the while loop continues to execute. Note the changes to my answer so now we're going to say n not r because r is holding a pointer to the Random object

Comment: @ThatDaveGuy : What about duplicate values in the map ?

Comment: Add a for loop that walks the array each time. You've got an index counter with i so you don't even have to walk to the end, just to where you are. I'll do an edit.

Comment: Instead of a loop how about a string that holds the entries you've already added? While n == i OR the number is in the list it chooses a new number. I haven't checked if this syntax is correct but it seems like a fine idea

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

```
public static String[] generateAssignments(final String... participants) {
  List<String> al = Arrays.asList(participants.clone());
  out: while (true) {
    Collections.shuffle(al);
    for (int i = 0; i < participants.length; i++) {
      if (al.get(i).equals(participants[i])) {
        continue out;
      }
    }
    break out;
  }
  return al.toArray(new String[0]);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] in = new String[] {"Hello", "World", "Goodbye"};
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(in));
  String[] out = generateAssignments(in);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(out));
}
```

Comment: @ElliotFrisch : Thanks for the reply. I thought about shuffle() too. but its not going to shuffle 100 %. what if the value in original array is mapped to value in generateAssignments , both are same ( which shouldnt be the case right ? )

Comment: @user2988851 Edited to add a while loop, check for that condition, and break the loop only when every element has moved.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch : but even if one element mapped equals then the shuffle() will be called. does it seem efficient ?

Comment: @user2988851 What are the odds of two elements mapping equal? Directly inverse to the length. Make sure you have more then one, or it'll loop forever.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch : How about I continue the loop in the code I wrote ? For selecting the random values and check the map if it contains ?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me locally:

```
/**
 * Assigns secret santa giftees.
 * 
 * @param participants
 *            The participants in the secret santa drawing
 * @return An array of assigned giftees for the participants.
 */
public static String[] generateAssignments(final String[] participants) {
    String[] ret = new String[participants.length];
    Arrays.fill(ret, "Andreas");
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but we need to shuffle the values right ?

Comment: If you provide me a unit test that can validate the "randomness" of a shuffle, I'll write a deterministic method that passes your test. In my answer this fact is leveraged to generate a linear time solution.